# Jquery get nth child of a matched row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Please see line with Prepend below.

```
$('#Area_Code').keyup(function(){ 
        var searchterm = $(this).val();
        if(searchterm.length > 3) {
            var match = $('tr.data-row:contains("' + searchterm + '")');
            var nomatch = $('tr.data-row:not(:contains("' + searchterm + '"))');
            $('#Sector1_Result').prepend(match)
            match.addClass('selected');
            nomatch.css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $('tr.data-row').css("display", "");
            $('tr.data-row').removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
```

This gets a row from a table and appends it, I only want a cell from a row , not the entire row.

Comment: If `match` represents just one row,, and you want one of its cells, then you can do `match[0].cells[n]`, where `n` is the 0-based index of the cell you want. But overall, you're not providing much info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). For example if `match` is the jQuery object containing the row, then you get the nth child whith:

```
match.children().get(n)
```

Comment: If you explain what is not working, then I might be able to help you, otherwise I'm not. Keep in mind that you cannot add table cells to anything else than rows (i.e. `#Sector1_Result` must be a table row). See, it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/WXN2S/.

Comment: Well, that's not what I wrote in my answer (did you read it?). If `match` is the row, then `match.children().get(1)` is its second cell. If you want to prepend that cell, you have to write `$('#Selector_Result').prepend(match.children().eq(1));`. Your code (`$('#Selector_Result').prepend(match)`) still prepends the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

I would directly write td selector on the table

html:

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>joy</td>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
$('td:contains("joy")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykZcN/1/